# why i can't cast nullptr to weak_ptr<>

Tags: c++, casting, null, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

```
class MyClass {
public:
     MyClass(std::weak_ptr<MyClass> parent){}
}
```

i want to do this:

```
auto newInstance = std::make_shared<MyClass>(nullptr);
```

or default value of weak_ptr argument is null, such as :

```
void function(int arg,std::weak_ptr<MyClass> obj = nullptr);
```

but, what i need is to do this instead:

```
auto newInstance = std::make_shared<MyClass>(std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(nullptr));
```

why is that?

Comment: BTW, next time, also include the compiler errors in your question

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Because a `weak_ptr` in concept can only be constructed from another `weak_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. It just doesn't make sense to construct from a raw pointer, whether it's `nullptr` or not.

You can use a default constructed `weak_ptr` (`std::weak_ptr<MyClass>()`) where you are trying to use `nullptr`:

```
auto newInstance = std::make_shared<MyClass>(std::weak_ptr<MyClass>());
void function(int arg,std::weak_ptr<MyClass> obj = std::weak_ptr<MyClass>());
```

Comment: `nullptr` has special type `nullptr_t` so raw pointers can not be implicitly converted to `nullptr_t`. Therefore I don't see any reasons to ban `weak_ptr<T>(nullptr)`.

Comment: @magras I wrote this answer years ago, and tbh I sort of agree with you. Fundamentally it makes sense that a weak pointer need to either be associated to a shared_ptr or unassociated. The standards committee obviously decided nullptr didn't convey unassociated as well as default constructed.

Comment: There is also the `.reset()` member function in `std::weak_ptr`

Answer (score -4):

A weak pointer's primary purpose is usually to know whether an object that might be destroyed by other code still exists. How could a weak pointer constructed from an ordinary pointer possibly know whether the object still exists? Can you even imagine a way this could possibly work?

Comment: I can imagine that, I think. Quite easily. :)

Comment: "A weak pointer's sole purpose is to know whether an object that might be destroyed by other code still exists" is a bit confusing statement. I would say this is facility of weak_ptr. The purpose of smart pointers is to automate memory management. Moreover there are some more facilities of weak_ptr: (1) as you said observing object without influence on it's life time (2) preventing so called "retain cycles" (when there is a circle of objects referencing each other with shared pointer thus keeping all objects alive and causing memory leaks) (3) can refer to pointed object returning shared_ptr.

Comment: How about when you want the weak_ptr to be auto-constructed to nullptr in the constructor? That's when I need this functionality.